# ASP.NET C# JSON Deserialize Nested Array: Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference

Tags: c#, json

I have found some logical examples online that seem like this should work, but I still am unable to parse through a nested JSON array to access and process each value within the array.  I can successfully access child parameters in other API call responses by doing something such as: string test = object.parameter1.parameter2.array[0].targetValue (only one value is in this array). However, I do not get the same results I think because of the syntax where there are many values within the array that may be causing the errors outlined below.

```
   private static string GetPositions()
    {

        var client = new RestClient("https://api.tdameritrade.com/v1/accounts/" + accountId);
        client.Timeout = -1;
        var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
        request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + ReadAccessToken());
        IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);

        dynamic positions = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(response.Content);

        var openPositions = "";


        //Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference
        //var openPositions = positions.securitiesAccount.positions[0].instrument.symbol;


        //Object reference not set to an instance of an object
        //foreach (var child in positions["securitiesAccount"]["positions"])
        //{
        //    openPositions = child["instrument"]["symbol"].ToString();
        //}

        //Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference    
        foreach (JObject child in positions["securitiesAccount"]["positions"].OfType<JObject>())
        {
            openPositions = child["instrument"]["symbol"].ToString();
        }

            return openPositions;
    }
```

An example of the nested JSON array I am trying to cycle through each open position and store in a database;  the only thing I'm having issues with is accessing each position within positions[] -

```
{
  "securitiesAccount": {
    "type": "type",
    "accountId": "id",
    "roundTrips": 0,
    "isDayTrader": false,
    "isClosingOnlyRestricted": false,
    "positions": [
      {
        "shortQuantity": 0,
        "averagePrice": 73.495,
        "currentDayProfitLoss": 7.56,
        "currentDayProfitLossPercentage": 0.76,
        "longQuantity": 14,
        "settledLongQuantity": 14,
        "settledShortQuantity": 0,
        "instrument": {
          "assetType": "EQUITY",
          "cusip": "1",
          "symbol": "symbol1"
        },
        "marketValue": 1001,
        "maintenanceRequirement": 300.3
      },
      {
        "shortQuantity": 0,
        "averagePrice": 17.659846153846,
        "currentDayProfitLoss": 12.33,
        "currentDayProfitLossPercentage": 1.12,
        "longQuantity": 65,
        "settledLongQuantity": 0,
        "settledShortQuantity": 0,
        "instrument": {
          "assetType": "EQUITY",
          "cusip": "2",
          "symbol": "symbol2"
        },
        "marketValue": 1115.4,
        "maintenanceRequirement": 557.7
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Any advice on how to accomplish this would be greatly appreciated.

--Updated code for reference--

```
   private static string GetPositions()
    {

        var client = new RestClient("https://api.tdameritrade.com/v1/accounts/" + accountId);
        client.Timeout = -1;
        var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
        request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + ReadAccessToken());
        IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);

        dynamic streamer = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(response.Content);

        var json = streamer.ToString();

        dynamic positions = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<OpenPositions>(json);

        var openPositions = positions.SecuritiesAccount.Positions[0].Instrument.Symbol.ToString();


        /*
        var test = "";
        OpenPositions securitiesAccount = new OpenPositions();
        SecuritiesAccount positions = new SecuritiesAccount();
        Position instrument = new Position();
        Instrument symbol = new Instrument();
        
        foreach (var child in json[securitiesAccount][positions])
        {
            test = child[instrument][symbol].ToString();
        }
        */

        //return test;


        return openPositions;
    }
```

Here are the classes converting the JSON parameters into C objects:

```
public partial class OpenPositions
{
    [JsonProperty("securitiesAccount")]
    public SecuritiesAccount SecuritiesAccount { get; set; }
}

public partial class SecuritiesAccount
{
    [JsonProperty("type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("accountId")]
    [JsonConverter(typeof(ParseStringConverter))]
    public long AccountId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("positions")]
    public Position[] Positions { get; set; }

}


public partial class Position
{

    [JsonProperty("instrument")]
    public Instrument Instrument { get; set; }

}

public partial class Instrument
{
    [JsonProperty("assetType")]
    public AssetType AssetType { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("cusip")]
    public string Cusip { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("symbol")]
    public string Symbol { get; set; }
}
```

var openPositions = positions.SecuritiesAccount.Positions[0].Instrument.Symbol.ToString(); is the code that throws the Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference exception.  However, that line of code is just to test that I can get at the nested string and the ultimate objective is to loop through each Position[] and return every open order there may be.

[image: Server Error in '/' Application]

Comment: Why not create required types for this json and deserialize to that class object? https://json2csharp.com/

Comment: I didn't know that was an option.  I'll try messing around with this to see how implementing it would best suit the need.

Comment: I created the classes and respective objects, but I still run into the "Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference" when trying to access the positions array.  For example, I know it's correctly setup because I can return my account id string from: var accountId = positions.SecuritiesAccount.AccountId.ToString();  however: var openPositions = positions.SecuritiesAccount.Positions[0].Instrument.Symbol.ToString(); or any combination tried with the Positions array, still throws the same error as when I directly deserialize the JSON response.  Any other suggestions or recommendations?

Comment: Can you update the question with your latest code changes? Also mention which line in the code throws the exception?

Comment: I was able to get the value of `positions.SecuritiesAccount.Positions[0].Instrument.Symbol.ToString()` after deserializing  the JSON to class object.

Comment: I added the classes and code above per the request.  Do you have more than one value, though?  In the use case context, there will be a multitude of open positions I am trying to cycle through and I'm just wondering if you returned one value, or multiple.

Comment: Try changing `dynamic positions = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<OpenPositions>(json);` to `var positions = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<OpenPositions>(json);`

Comment: It's still throwing the same exception at that line of code.  I have this working for a different method, so I don't understand why it's specifically failing in the above code unless it has to do with multiple nested values within the array.

            dynamic tradeData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(response.Content);
            string transactionDate = tradeData[0].transactionDate;
I can get the entire JSON response to display, I just can't parse the nested array values for some reason.

Comment: @Chetan Ranpariya - it was an issue with the API call return.  I can get the nested values.  Many thanks for the input.